# sql left join with distinct correct?

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I'm trying to do a join between tables 1 and 2 which have a 1 to many relationship.

table1 has the following fields

- createdate
- contact
- tkey (surrogate key)

table2 has the following fields

- tkey (primary key)
- status
- userfld1
- description

I want to show all items in table2 with their corresponding items in table1 grouped by table2.userfld1

```
select distinct t2.userfld1, t2.status, t2.description, t1.createdate, t1.contact
from table2 as t2 left join table1 as t1 
      on t2.tkey = t1.tkey 
group by t2.userfld1
```

is this correct?

Comment: This SQL is malformed.  The aliases t1 and t2 are not defined - `table2 left join table1.tkey` is not valid syntax.  You'll also get an error as you're including fields in your select that are not group'ed by.  Could you define your required result set more precisely - what do you mean by 'grouped by table2.userfld1'?

Comment: Provide example data - I'm not convinced you want to be joining the tables based on the `tkey` values.

Comment: I think the terminology is a bit off. My guess is that 'group by' should be 'order by' and 'surrogate key' should be 'foreign key'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that's not correct, you can't select columns that aren't in the group by unless they are contained in an aggregate function. And I think what you are asking for doesn't even make sense. My best guess is that you mean ORDER BY, not GROUP BY:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t2.userfld1, t2.status, t2.description, t1.createdate, t1.contact
FROM table2 t2
LEFT JOIN table1 t1
ON t2.tkey = t1.tkey 
ORDER BY t2.userfld1
```

Three other errors that I've fixed:

- SELECT ... FROM not SELECT ... WHERE
- You should join with a table, not a column.
- You had no aliases after the table names, but later refer to these missing aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is order by, not group by, and I also fixed your query:

```
select t2.userfld1, t2.status, t2.description, t1.createdate, t1.contact
where table2 t2 left join table1 t1
      on t2.tkey = t1.tkey 
order by t2.userfld1
```

Is this what you were looking for?